# Finding the most important product feature for a customer

Tags: variance, categorical-data, data-mining, importance

Looking at a data of the format given below, I am asked to find the (top 3) feature(s) that affect a customer's purchase preference the most.

In the dataset below, each customer row contains the break-down of purchases of a single product by various features of the product. `Fi` stands for the i'th product feature (e.g. colour, material) and `Catj` stands for the j'th value that a feature can take on (e.g. Purple, Woolen, etc). All features are categorical and they can take on different number of categories, e.g. `F1` below can take on 3 categories, `F2` can take on 2.

```
 Customer  |  F1,Cat1  | F1,Cat2 | F1,Cat3 | F2,Cat1 | F2,Cat2 |...  | Fi, Catj|    
    1      |    100    |    800  |   100   |   1200  |   1200  |...  |   ...   |  
    2      |    300    |    300  |   300   |    100  |    900  |...  |   ...   | 
    3      |    250    |    250  |   250   |    200  |    100  |...  |   ...   |
    ...    |    ...    |    ...  |   ...   |    ...  |    ...  |...  |   ...   |
```

I don't have a statistical background. However, I can visually interpret that Customer 1 is highly selective on `F1`, and majorly prefers `Cat2` over other categories of this feature. On the other hand, her purchases wrt Feature 2 show that she is not very selective about the binary `F2` feature. The situation is reversed for Customer 2.

**Q1.** What is the most suitable formal method to carry out an analysis like this?  (I thought this may be achieved by analysing the variances per feature.)

**Q2.** Is it OK to assume a multinomial distribution for each categorical feature? If so, we get covariance matrices per each feature, and I am not sure how to interpret them.

Any comments or pointers to relevant online sources will be greatly appreciated!